# Pass an include parameter inside a liquid call

Tags: jekyll, liquid, templating

I have a page say index.html and a file with liquid code called `tags`. I want to pass a parameter which I specify in index.html to a liquid call in `tags`. Namely,

**index.html**

```
<div>
  {% include tags param="site.categories" %}
</div>
```

**Tags**

```
{% assign tags_list = {{ include.param }} %}
...
```

The `{% assign tags_list = {{ include.param }} %}` does not work for some reason. Is it possible to do so because this allows me to use `tags` file for multiple purposes? Instead of writing liquid calls in every page Iwould be able to just do `{% include tags param="something" %}`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, `{% include tags param="site.categories" %}` is not passing the `site.categories` hash but the `"site.categories"` string.

The right syntax is :

```
{% include tags.html param=site.categories %}
```